# JaCoCo exclusions are being ignored by Sonar

Tags: gradle, jacoco, sonarcloud

I use the Gradle JaCoCo plugin, according to the exclusion list some folders must be excluded from the test coverage check. But when I run `gradle sonar` all these folders are being processed by Sonarcloud.

How can I force SonarCloud to ignore these folders?

[image]

```
jacocoTestReport {
dependsOn test
reports {
    xml.required = true
    html.required = true
}
afterEvaluate {
    classDirectories.setFrom(files(classDirectories.files.collect {
        fileTree(dir: it, exclude: [
                'by/litvin/localsandbox/model/*',
                'by/litvin/localsandbox/mapper/*',
                'by/litvin/localsandbox/data/*',
                'by/litvin/localsandbox/data/*',
                'by/litvin/localsandbox/messaging/event/*',
                'by/litvin/localsandbox/messaging/serializer/*',
                'by/litvin/localsandbox/config/*',
                'by/litvin/localsandbox/LocalSandboxApplication.*'
        ])
    }))
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution, JaCoCo exclusion list is not enough, you need to exclude these packages in the sonar plugin config as well:

```
sonarqube {
    properties {
        def projectPath = "**/*by/litvin/localsandbox"
        def exclusionList = [
                "${projectPath}/model/*",
                "${projectPath}/config/*",
                "${projectPath}/data/*",
                "${projectPath}/messaging/serializer/*",
                "${projectPath}/messaging/event",
                "${projectPath}/LocalSandboxApplication.*"
        ].join(', ')
        property "sonar.coverage.exclusions", exclusionList
    }
}
```

Comment: i was about to post the same answer.

Comment: This doesn't work the same way: "JaCoCo exclusions are "classname based" while on SonarQube side we are working with files path." (https://groups.google.com/g/sonarqube/c/VwEE_ZD2KzI?pli=1). I needed to modify my `exclusionList` to work both for JaCoCo. Maybe it isn't always possible